# Error in opening Mass Effect 1 on Windows 7

Tags: pc, technical-issues, windows-7, mass-effect

**Ok, so I have spent several hours troubleshooting this.**

[image: This is the error I keep getting.]
This is what I get both when I open the Launcher and hit play, and when I directly open the .exe file that it claims to not be able to find.

***I have done the following to try to attempt to fix this:***

- Installed the 1.02 Patch
- Running in Windows XP Compatibility Mode
- Running as Admin
- Updating Graphics Driver
- Setting UseEffectsProcessing from True to False in the *BaseEngine.ini* file

Does anyone have any other suggestions? I'm trying to run it on my Windows 7 Toshiba Satellite, Intel Centrino processor, and 3GB of ram.

Comment: Do you meet the minimum requirements. Your computer isn't as powerful as many current computers, so it might be worth a try to see so. This website will tell you the minimum requirements, adjust requirements and recomended requirements: http://www.game-debate.com/games/index.php?g_id=12&game=Mass%20Effect

Comment: Thanks for the list. I'm pretty sure I meet all the requirements, but my processor is an Intel Core2 Duo with 1.83GHz. Do you think that could be a problem?

Comment: You did say you had Centrino in your question though? What is your GPU, that could also be a culprit

Comment: No, your Intel Core2 meets the requirements

Comment: Are you running through Steam? You should perform a file integrity check if so.

Comment: I'm not running through steam, installed it from the disc. My video card is Mobile Intel 965 Express Chipset family.

Comment: Sorry @Erin, but I guess you got to get a new computer :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**The reason you cannot play is because of your GPU**

The error that is occurring is stemming from a problem between the game and your Video Card, specifically the command to use GMatrix2D (GPF Error).[Source](http://www.gamespot.com/forums/pc-mac-discussion-1000004/mass-effect-pc-problems-27141125/)

Your are trying to run the game on a Mobile Intel Express Chipset. According to a few sources, linked here will be the steampowered forums, the game does not support the use of Mobile Intel Chipset. I would recomend you upgrade your GPU, but seeing you are using a mobile GPU, this would not be easier/impossible.[Source](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1876599)

Try to play on your desktop if you can, or get a more modern Laptop that has a newer mobile GPU that can run it

***NOTE: Not all Mobile GPU fail to play the game, only Mobile Intel Express Chipsets and old GPU***

---

## Sources:

[Yet another annoyed Mass Effect customer](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1876599)

[Mass Effect PC problems](http://www.gamespot.com/forums/pc-mac-discussion-1000004/mass-effect-pc-problems-27141125/)

Comment: Nice of GL (or Mass Effect) to segfault rather than providing some nice incompatibility message!!

Comment: I know right @LightnessRacesinOrbit? You would think its some issue with the file path, cause it says that, but who knows.